# Uploaded files are not showing correctly in some users

Tags: files

Uploaded files are not showing correctly in drupal 7.12. However this issue occurs only with some old users and newly created users are working fine.

what might be the cause of the issue. Can anybody please suggest/help to fix the issue?
Thanks in advance!
http://prntscr.com/7ang7h

Comment: What kind of modules are you using with this? And what exactly is wrong with the file name? Is the correct file being saved to disk (/files folder)? Maybe some more information could help here. Also, the current version of D7 is 7.37, you may want to consider updating Drupal and updating any modules you are using as well. Just the changelog items between 7.12 and 7.37 are enough to say it really needs to be done (Drupal 7 Changelog https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/CHANGELOG.txt/7). It's a good bet that after updating code and database that your issue could fix itself. I've seen it happen.

Comment: It is drupal core mechanism, no any contributed modules are used for user registration. Regarding correct file being saved to disk: I'm not sure as users are created long time ago and this issue raised recently however testing with new user, everything is working perfectly.

Comment: first - when including images in a question or answer, please embed the image, not a link to the image - if the link dies, the question becomes useless. second - update your drupal site - there are a couple of MAJOR security issues that were addressed in the 7.3-- series, and to avoid possible hacking, you need to do something about it now.  third - how are they not showing correctly - you need to provide more information

Comment: This issue has been fixed and the issue was related to database and was due to loss of chunk of data and resetting primary key on file_managed table.